# Something like map algebra or cell statistics for vector format

Tags: overlapping-features, gis-principle

I work in environmental consultancy and I have recently been tasked with generating the 'Environmental Zoning' for a road project. I use GIS in my everyday work but nothing too advanced.

I'm not sure the term 'Environmental Zoning' means what I  think it means in English, but I can't seem to find any other translation. Anyway, what it means in my country is to overlay a bunch of information about the environmental vulnerability of certain places, for example, a place could be highly vulnerable because it's prone to earthquakes, another place could be highly vulnerable because it's a lake that must be protected, because it's a forest with endangered species, or it could have a low vulnerability because it's an urban area, etcetera...

My job is to get all these layers of information (earthquake risk, land use, protected areas, sacred places...) assign a vulnerability category (1 to 5) and overlay them all, so that the areas with the highest vulnerability values will come out on top.

The following image shows the process I'm trying to describe:

[image: Environmental Zoning Example]

The workaround I was able to find for this by google searching is to create a union of all the layers I need, getting new smaller polygons with columns showing the vulnerability value of feature 1, feature 2, feature 3 and so on. Then, calculating the max value in field calculator and finally dissolving the result based on the max field to clean up a little.

I can't help but feel that this takes a lot of extra steps, and when needing to combine more than five feature classes, it starts to feel confusing and I'm afraid I'll mess up at some point. I thought maybe I could get the results I wanted with the merge  tool but I couldn't figure out a way to make that work.

I also found some people just convert their feature classes to raster format and perform the operations they need in map algebra or cell statistics (ArcGIS), so I'm now giving it a try, it seems like a much smoother process to me, but I have to calculate areas from the result so I'll have to convert back to vector, I don't fully understand how to deal with 'cell size' or what size would be acceptable and not cause too many errors in my final result.

So I'm wondering if maybe there is a similar tool to 'Cell Statistics' for vector format that I just haven't found yet.

Comment: "Site suitability" is another term for what you're calling "Environmental Zoning". You're already on the right path for potential techniques (either unioning or converting to raster). You can do the union all in one step, so the difference between unioning three layers or ten layers should just be a matter of processing time, not extra steps. If you're not comfortable understanding appropriate cell size (aka pixel size, resolution) you might want to go through some introductory working with raster data tutorials and/or learn more about your data layers (any remote sensing derived?).

Comment: You have a tag for ArcGIS Pro and mention QGIS and ArcGIS Pro in your question body. Please decide which it is that you wish to ask about in this particular question or if you want to be software agnostic then remove all references to products and tag you question as a [tag:gis-principle] instead.

Comment: I think what you’re looking for is region topology.

Comment: @PolyGeo thank you, I changed the post so it doesn't mention any specific software. Also I looked into region topology but all I can find is topology alone, which I understand is helpful for making sure polygons don't overlap and stuff like that. Do you have a resource you could point me to in order to learn about region topology?

Comment: ArcGIS calls it ["Overlay"](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/analysis/an-overview-of-the-overlay-toolset.htm), more specifically, Union.

Comment: @ycartwhelen Thank you! I'm now looking into site suitability, indeed, it is very similar to what I'm trying to do, I can see the general practice is to work in raster format for these types of processes so I'm gonna follow your advice and learn more about working with raster data.

Comment: This is easily accomplished by vector overlay. Using rasters to approximate vector overlay is possible, but lossy.

Answer (score 1):

I think that what you are describing is known as region topology (overlapping polygons, polygon fragmentation and recombination) and one of the few places that you can read a little about it nowadays is at [Overlapping polygons in a coverage: Regions](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/coverage-toolbox/overlapping-polygons-in-a-coverage-regions.htm).  It was a functionality that emerged from Esri UK in the very late 1980s and early 1990s, and became part of core ARC/INFO (ArcInfo Workstation) soon after that.

It was based on the coverage data model and had a syntax developed which always reminded me of map algebra.  I was surprised that it never became part of the geodatabase data model, at least not in any form that I recognized as region topology.  I cannot find the syntax used with regions described anywhere now but I recollect it referenced polygons that were part of an input coverage used to build region topology by using `$$<original_coverage_name>`.

It is highly related to Union and all the polygon overlay tools but sat above them.